# How does the linux kernel know how many threads/cpu exists on a particular HW platform

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, software-design

I have a simple question. How does the Linux Kernel know how many threads a platform has, and how would a VM abstract the into vCPU? I would like to modify some kernel code to show that there is N threads when after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an x86 system, the number of hyperthreads is reported by the BIOS in the ACPI tables. In particular, in the APIC table. There is one local APIC per hyperthread, and the APIC table lists the APIC ID of each local APIC. The kernel uses the APIC IDs in the APIC table to send a message to each of the threads to wake it up. The kernel does not probe the hardware itself.

In a virtual platform, the ACPI tables are constructed by the VMM, and the APIC table reports the number of VCPUs configured for the VM.